# How to compute $\sum_{\gamma \in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z), \|\gamma\|<10}\frac{1}{\|\gamma \|^4}$ in Sagemath

Tags: sagemath

Sorry for this question, but how to compute

$$\sum_{\gamma \in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z), \|\gamma\|<1000}\frac{1}{\|\gamma \|^4}$$

in Sagemath? Here the norm is just Frobebius norm (square root of the sum of squares of entries)

I tried something like

```
    from sage.all import *
        G = SL(2,ZZ)
        s = 0
        for r in G:
            if r.norm() < 10:
                s += 1/r.norm()^4
        s
```

but there is an error and I couldn't figure out how to use `SL(2,ZZ)` properly.

---

To save the computational effort, I changed the range from 1000 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Sagemath syntax, but G is an infinite group. So your `for` loop is asking to loop over infinitely many things. That's an abstract reason why that approach won't work, syntax aside.

You know that all four entries of a matrix that contributes to the sum will be in $\left\{-1000,\cdots,1000\right\}$ . So it's not efficient, but you could sum over $(a,b,c,d)\in\left\{-1000,\cdots,1000\right\}^4$ and only add the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}}$ contribution when $ ad-bc=1$.

You could improve efficiency by summing like this:

$$\sum_{a=-1000}^{1000}\sum_{b=-\sqrt{1000^2-a^2}}^{\sqrt{1000^2-a^2}}\sum_{c=-\sqrt{1000^2-a^2-b^2}}^{\sqrt{1000^2-a^2-b^2}}\sum_{d=-\sqrt{1000^2-a^2-b^2-c^2}}^{\sqrt{1000^2-a^2-b^2-c^2}}$$

And more by not looking over all those $d$-values. Instead, check if $\frac{1+bc}{a}$ is an integer. If so, that is the only value of $d$ to use. And in that case do include the contribution to the overall sum. (Of course you have to handle the $a=0$ tuples separately.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty method (there's probably something better, but I don't have the time to look for it right now):

We know that an element $M \in \mathsf{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ of (frobenius) norm $< 1000$ looks like a matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ with integer entries, $ad-bc = 1$, and $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2} < 1000$. Now for the crude part: This, in particular, tells us that each $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d| < 1000$, so we can just check all of these.

In code, we get:

```
N = 1000

total = 0
count = 0
for a in range(-N,N):
  for b in range(-N,N):
    for c in range(-N,N):
      for d in range(-N,N):
        count += 1
        if count % 1000 == 0: print(count, "/", (2*N)^4)

        norm = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)
        if norm < 1000 and a*d - b*c == 1:
          total += (1/norm^4).n()
```

though be warned, this will take a *very* long time! It will print out how far along in the process it is as it goes, but it will have to try $2001^4 \approx 10^{13}$ many matrices. You can be more clever with the endpoints in order to speed this up, but I'll leave that optimization to you.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Sorry for this dump question, but what is a slick way to output the sum as a numerical number instead of quotient of two huge integers? (I changed it from 1000 to 10 now it should be computable)

Comment: @taylor -- use `total.n()` to get a decimal representation

Answer (score 0):

Below, the matrix $A$ stays for $A=A(a,b,c,d)$, slight abuse of notation, it is seen as a function in the variables $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$.
Its norm will be denoted by $|A|$, so $|A|^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.
I will set
$$
N=1000
$$
for an easy typing.
Let $\Gamma=\operatorname{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$.
Let $S=S(N)$ be the sum to be computed:
$$
S =S(N)=\sum
_{A\in\Gamma\\ |A|<N}
\frac 1{|A^4|}
\ ,
$$
First of all, we compute the contribution of all those $A$ that involve at least one zero entry. If $a=0$, then $bc=-1$, there are two cases for $b$, $b=\pm1$, and $c$ is adjusted accordingly as $c=-1/b=\-p1$, and the value of $d$ obeys $-N<d<N$. The corresponding sum is
$$
S_{a=0}
=2\sum_{-N<d<N} \frac 1{(0+1+1+d^2)^2} 
=4\sum_{0<k<N} \frac 1{(0+1+1+k^2)^2} +\frac 2{(0+1+1+0)^2} 
\ ,
$$
and it can be easily computed numerically. In a similar manner, introduce $S_{d=0}$, then $S_{a=0}=S_{d=0}$. The term with $a=d=0$ is considered in both sums, so the contribution to $S$ from the matrices $A$ with $ad=0$ is
$$
S_{ad=0} = 
8\sum_{0<k<N} \frac 1{(0+1+1+k^2)^2} +\frac 2{(0+1+1+0)^2} 
\ .
$$
A similar story concerns the case $bc=0$, and the contribution of both cases is
$$
S_{abcd=0} = 
16\sum_{0<k<N} \frac 1{(0+1+1+k^2)^2} + 1 
\ .
$$
This "special case" is cleared.
Consider now the contribution from all other cases.

Can we have two (or more) entries of same *maximal* modulus. If two such entries are in the same line or column, then this common modulus value divides the determinant, so it is $\pm 1$. So all entries are $\pm 1$ by maximality. Taking the determinant modulo two we can replace all $\pm 1$ by $1$ modulo two, so the determinant is zero modulo two. Contradiction. So the two values with maximal modulus are on the same diagonal. Let $k$ be this modulus, so the product on this diagonal is $k^2$ in modulus. Then on the other diagonal we have in modulus at most $(k-1)^2$, and the difference can not be $\pm 1$.

So there is exactly one maximal modulus entry, call it key.
If this key is in the main diagonal $(a,d)$, it's ok, else we exchange columns, and multiply the first column with $-1$. So take the contribution below times $2$. If the key is $A$ it's ok, else exchange $a$ and $d$. So take the contribution below times $4$. The key is now $a$. If the key $a$ is negative, replace $A$ by $-A$. So the key $a$ becomes positive.
And we take the contribution below times $8$. In the diagonal $(b,c)$ insist that $b>0$ by possibly exchanging signs simultaneously.
So contribution below times $16$.

Since i like positive numbers (when writing code), i'd like to have also $d>0$. Well, if $d<0$ we change signs in the row $(c,d)$, thus changing the determinant from $+1$ to $-1$. But now we have a clear situation, $c$ is also positive, so $a,b,c,d>0$, $ad-bc =\pm1$, and $a>b,c,d$. I case of $b=c$ we consider the term once, else $b\ne c$, and we insist that $b>c$ after exchanging, and considering this term times two.

Now there is a simple path to implement. We let $a$ run in the interval $(1,N)$. Then $d$ runs in the interval $(0,a)$. We build $ad\pm 1$ and factorize it in positive integers as $bc$ with $c\le b<a$. And of course,
we restrict to the case $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 < N^2$. In case of $b=c$ we consider the term $1/(a^2 +b^2 +c^2+d^2)$ times one, else times two.

---

Code:

```
R = RealField(300)

def S0(N):
    return R(1) + 16*sum([ 1/(R(2) + k^2)^2 for k in [1..N-1]])

def S1(N):
    S = R(0)
    for a in [1..N-1]:
        for d in [1..a-1]:
            if a^2 + d^2 > N^2:    break    # the d loop
            for bc in (a*d - 1, a*d + 1):
                for c in bc.divisors():
                    b = ZZ(bc / c)
                    if b < c:    break    # the c loop
                    norm2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2
                    if b < a and norm2 < N^2:
                        S += R(1) / norm2^2 * (1 if b==c else 2)
    return 16*S
```

And we get:

```
sage: S0(1000) + S1(1000)
4.18456554053875394382856565430709947660176138858177166092612407947397830461918770929226114
```

I hope this is ok, no time for structural checks.

---

**Note:** Alternative implementation in pari/gp:

```
{S0(N) = 1. + 16.*sum(k=1, N-1, 1./(2. + k^2)^2)}
{S1(N) = local(S,a,b,c,d,norm2);
 S = 0.;
 for(a=2, N-1, 
   for(d=1, a-1,
     if(a^2 + d^2 < N^2,
       for(pow=0, 1, bc = a*d + (-1)^pow;
         divs = divisors(bc);
         for(k=1, length(divs),
           c = divs[k]; b = bc / c; norm2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2;
           if(c < a && b < a && norm2 < N^2,
             S += 1 / norm2^2; 
           ))))));
 16*S;}
```

This gives:

```
? \p 100
   realprecision = 115 significant digits (100 digits displayed)
? #
   timer = 1 (on)
? S0(1000) + S1(1000)
cpu time = 9,337 ms, real time = 9,347 ms.
%24 = 4.184565540538753943828565654307099476601761388581771660926124079473978304619187709292261024171064063
```